# Iterate JavaScript object containing array and nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a video timeline containing several videos and I'm trying to create popups to go along with each video

I am trying to get the popups to appear when the video plays and if there is more than one object in the corresponding array, go through them and then carry on with the video

I've tried getting the objects entries and looping over them but it gives me both as opposed to just one

```js
let popups = {
  0: [{
      type: 'alert',
      text: 'Alert text',
    },
    {
      type: 'warning',
      text: 'Warning text',
    },
  ],
  1: [{
    type: 'caution',
    text: 'Caution text',
  }, ],
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you write example output that you expect? What did you try? Did you encounter some issues?

Comment: Add your effort. It's always better to point out **what** you have done wrong instead of giving you the solution.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] it and add relevant code along with expected output. `go through them` means what?  -  `gives me both` ? both what?

Comment: Yeah, I'll admit that was a terrible explanation and even after I typed it out several times I wasn't sure about it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you just need a foreach inside a foreach:

```js
let popups = [
  [
     {
        type: 'alert',
        text: 'Alert text',
     },
    {
    type: 'warning',
        text: 'Warning text',
    },
],
  [
        {
            type: 'caution',
            text: 'Caution text',
        },
    ],
];

// Show all objects
popups.forEach((popup) => popup.forEach((entry) => console.log(entry)))
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the approach I stumbled over myself after posting this question. I just had to add an if statement to make sure it was on the same video index

Answer (score 0):

The popups is an object so you first need to iterate it, there is the Object.entries() method in js.

```
let popupsToDisplay = [];
Object.entries(popups).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    value.forEach(innerObject => popupsToDisplay.push(innerObject))
})
```

Comment: I was debating using the Object.entries() method, but eventually decided to go down the Object.values() and Object.keys() method instead as it was easier to get the values I needed and keep them separate